# nuxt-link as an image

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

What do I have to do to use a `nuxt-link` as an image?

When I display an image in Vue, I usually do:

```
<img src="~assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg">
```

but when I do the same with a `nuxt-link`, the path to the file does not get evaluated.

```
# this is not working

<nuxt-link 
  tag="img" 
  src="~assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg" 
  to="/locations">
</nuxt-link>
```

What can I do to solve this?

**EDIT:**

It works though if I do:

```
<template>
    <nuxt-link 
      :src="image" 
      tag="img" 
      to="/locations">
    </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
import image from '~/assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: image
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: in your first example you have `src="~assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg"` instead of `~/assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg`

Comment: @kalidou.diagne - this is how you are supposed to include assets in nuxt. since this does not work in plain JS i had to adopt it to use it inside a variable. thanks for taking the time anyway! :)

Comment: @PeterPiper So you've answered your own question (via the edit), correct?

Comment: @tony19 - it works but it's kind of ugly imho ;) - i am still wondering if this is how you are supposed to use images as nuxt-links

Answer (score 4):

You can do without a variable in data.

```
# this is working

<nuxt-link 
  tag="img" 
  :src="require('~/assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg')" 
  to="/locations">
</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this [link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link), the tag prop is deprecated in vue-router 4 and should be replaced with v-slot. So arkadij_ok's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58796352/17124790) would now look like this:

```
<nuxt-link
  v-slot="{navigate}"
  to="/locations"
>
  <img 
   :src="require('~/assets/icons/filterLinkButton.svg')"
   role="link"
   @click="navigate"
  />
</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: this seems like the correct answer for vue >= 3

Comment: I'm using it on nuxt 2 since using the original solution gives a warning about the deprecated feature. It makes sense to use it with vue 2 incase one wants to upgrade his/her project later.

Answer (score 1):

I have used an image as a nuxt-link by placing the image inside of the nuxt-link tag.
[a screen shot of a nuxt-link with an img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSRZe.png)
[The html viewed with chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jga3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the documentation if you're using [webpack](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#webpack) you can use that alias (~assets) inside your css files, but apparently you need to use the ~/ version on your template, also take a look at the approach bellow using the static folder I think that suits you better since the asset you used in your question can be placed in the static folder and get rid of the alias